# how to search for strings with different language code

Tags: sparql

I need to search items in two graphs with the same string, but different language codes ("xx"@en and "xx"@eng - from wordnet). obviously 
"xx"@en is not equal to "xx"@eng.

it can be done with (prefix nlp suitably defined):

```
select * where {
   ?a nlp:lemma ?as . 
   ?b rdfs:label ?bs . 
   filter (str(?as)=str(?bs)) . 
     # more code using ?a and ?b
}
```

However, this query takes too long and is wasteful. It should be possible to do something like:

```
?a nlp:lemma ?s . 
?b rdfs:label ?s .
```

but i cannot see how - short of manually change all `@eng` in the wordnet triples to `@en` - which i would rather not do.

any solution? 
thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You could cut you search space down by filtering only for `en` and `eng`, but the only way to compare the string portion of a language-labeled string is to convert them to a string.

I.e. the following could be more efficient if there are language-labeled strings other than `en` and `eng`:

```
select * where {
   ?a nlp:lemma ?as . 
   ?b rdfs:label ?bs . 
   filter (lang(?as) = "en" || lang(?as) = "eng")
   filter (str(?as)=str(?bs)) . 
     # more code using ?a and ?b
}
```

Comment: thank you - it reduced the query processing time 4 times!

Comment: i ended up by adding both `@en` and `@eng` literals to the triples i had produced. now it really runs fast. i cannot understand why wordnet-princeton uses a different language code.

Comment: The codes are ISO-639-2/T (3 characters) in stead of the ISO-639-1 (2 characters) which is more common in RDF. It would be useful to have a function to convert between these!