# search for literal with different language code

Tags: sparql

I have two graphs, in one the literals are tagged (`@de`) in the other untagged. I need a join between the two. The trivial solution with a filter runs very slow.

```
WHERE {
 ?tok nlp:lemma ?lem . 
 ?tok2 wn:form ?t . 
 filter (?tok2 = ?t) . 
 ...
```

An improved version which works with fuseki is

```
WHERE {
 ?tok nlp:lemma ?lem .
 Bind (str(?lem) as ?lems) .
 ?lu :orthForm ?lems .
 ...
```

I tried `?lu :xx (str(?lem)) .` but this is flagged as an error. Why?
Similarly, using `value ?lems {str(?lem)}.`

I assume naively that the bind does not create much overhead, thus the above solution probably o.k.

Would the same approach work for searching when the language codes are different [my previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42589529/how-to-search-for-strings-with-different-language-code)

Comment: I don't get the first example. The FILTER looks strange or do you really want to have that subject and object are the same?

Answer (score 1):

The only thing allowed in a triple pattern are variables, URIs, literals (in object) and bnodes.  Hence instead of the pattern `?lu :xx (str(?lem))`, you will need to use a BIND or projection to convert the variable to a string.  Taking the first example:

```
WHERE {
   ?lu :xx ?langLem .
   BIND(str(?langLem) AS ?lem)
}
```

Or, using projection:

```
SELECT (str(?langLem) AS ?lem)
WHERE {
   ?lu :xx ?langLem .
}
```

I assume you are trying to use the `VALUES` statement in `value ?lems {str(?lem)}`.  `VALUES` is normally used to bind variables to a set of values, e.g.:

```
VALUES ?lem { :Euclid :Gauss }
?lem rdfs:label ?label .
```

...binds `?lem` to `:Euclid` and `:Gauss` and executes the query, returning the union of results.  I.e. it is the same as:

```
{ :Euclid rdfs:label ?label }
UNION
{ :Gauss rdfs:label ?label }
```